# error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String Request.Method.GET,

Tags: android, json, android-studio, get, android-volley

I'm attempting to connect my app to the server, but I'm receiving an error message.

I'm trying to connect my app to the server using the volley library, however whenever I execute my code, I receive the following error:

> error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

Please help!

This line is where the error is thrown:

> testArr = (JSONArray) response.get("results");

````
private void searchRecipe(String search) {
        searchRecipe = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
        // Please add your API key
        String URL = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=" + search + "&number=10&addRecipeInformation=true&instructionsRequired=true&apiKey=";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                response -> {
                    try {
                        testArr = (JSONArray) response.get("results");
                        Log.i(TAG, "search results:" + String.valueOf(testArr));
                        for (int i = 0; i < testArr.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1;
                            jsonObject1 = testArr.getJSONObject(i);
                            searchRecipe.add(new Recipe(jsonObject1.optString("id"), jsonObject1.optString("title"), jsonObject1.optString("image"),
                                    Integer.parseInt(jsonObject1.optString("servings")), Integer.parseInt(jsonObject1.optString("readyInMinutes"))));
                        }

                        
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }```
````

Comment: Where and how did you define testArr?

Comment: @blackapps in the main class: private JSONArray testArr;

Comment: Define an int and do not cast the result as the error states that you get an int.